# JS/jQuery: How can I automatically wrap <a href> tags around <img />s with the href being dynamic based on the img src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, href, word-wrap

Heads up: I am quite new to Javascript and have so far only written very basic scripts based on jQuery.
I am a quick study though..

What I am after is a way to:

1) identify  tags

2) read the img tags

3) wrap the  tag with an `<a href>` tag with a dynamic link based on the src of the img.

Example:

```
<img src="../../img_T/Culture/C_01/c_01_abb_005.jpg" width="310" height="180" alt="image1">
```

should become

```
<a href="../../img_L/Culture/C_01/c_01_abb_005.jpg"><img src="../../img_T/Culture/C_01/c_01_abb_005.jpg" width="310" height="180" alt="C 01 Abb 005"></a>
```

I am thinking that reading the src of each image and writing it to a variable, then reading that variable and replacing the /img_T/ with /img_L/ and then writing that to a new variable which can then be simply added to each href.

This is how far I have gotten, but this does not work at all:

```
/* in the comments 'xxx' represents a different unique image string */
/* This should get the <img src="../img_T/xxx" /> string as text and store it. */
var $imgSrc        =    $(".displaywrapper img").attr("src");

/* This part should use the above sourced <img src="../img_T/xxx" string and replace ../img_T/ of the src with ../img_L/ and store it in var = imgLink. */
var imgLink        =    $imgSrc.text().replace("img_T","img_L");

/* This part should then wrap the <img src="../img_T/xxx" /> so it becomes <a href="..img_L/xxx"><img src="../img_T/xxx" /></a> */
$(".displaywrapper img").each(function(){.wrap("<a href="imgLink"></a>")});
```

Thanks for reading.
Jannis

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".displayWrapper img").each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src').replace('img_T','img_L');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src);
        $(this).wrap(a);
    });
});
```

Line 1: Wait for the document [`to be ready`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24(document).ready()) before doing anything..
Line 2: Loop through each image using jQuery's [`each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each#callback) function.
Line 3: Get the current image's src with [`attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) and replace `img_T` with `img_L`
Line 4: [`Dynamically create`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument) a new `<a>` tag and set it's href attribute to the `src` in Line 3
Line 5: [`wrap`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap) the `<a>` tag around the `<img`> tag.

Comment: I don't see why that's necessary if he's in control of his HTML and it will be run once when the document loads.

Comment: thanks! 
But there is still something not working, at least not in my website.

If you can, please have a look at it in action, i promise this is not a blatant plug of my website: 
http://bgarchitect.co.nz/culture/new-flora/

I have added the code above but it simply does not take effect

Comment: my apologies. the script DOES work. the error is somewhere else as the jQuery fancyzoom plugin does not pick up the link.
Thank you very much!

Comment: update: I have found the other bug that was not in this script and everything works now.
thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the images clickable, do this:

```
$(".displayWrapper img").click(function(){
  document.location.href = this.src.replace("img_T", "img_L");
});
```